# Maximum call stack size exceeded in object practice

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, syntax-error

I'm currently learning to code and am on JavaScript. At the moment I am practicing with the use of objects by creating a random meal generator but I am very stuck. I keep getting the error "Maximum Call Stack Size Exceeded" could you please explain why and how I can fix it? Here's the code:

```
let menu={
  _courses:{
    appetizers:[],
    mains:[],
    desserts:[],
  },
  get appetizers(){
      return this.appetizers;
  },
  set appetizers(appetizersIn){
      this._courses.appetizers = appetizersIn;
  },
  get mains(){
      return this.mains;
  },
  set mains(mainsIn){
      this._courses.mains=mainsIn;
  },
  get desserts(){
      return this.desserts;
  },
  set desserts(dessertsIn){
      this._courses.desserts=dessertsIn;
  },
  get _courses(){
    return{
      appetizers: this.appetizers,
      mains: this.mains,
      desserts: this.desserts
    }
  },
  addDishToCourse(courseName,dishName,dishPrice){
      const dish ={
        dishName,
        dishPrice,
      }
      this._courses[courseName].push(dish);
  },
  getRandomDishFromCourse(courseName){
      const dishes=this._courses[courseName];
      const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random()*dishes.length);
      return dishes[randomIndex];
  },
generateRandomMeal: function(){
  const appetizer = this.getRandomDishFromCourse(appetizers);
  const main = this.getRandomDishFromCourse(mains);
  const dessert = this.getRandomDishFromCourse(desserts);
  const totalPrice=appetizer.price+main.price+dessert.price;
  return `Your meal consists of ${appetizer.name}, ${main.name} and ${dessert.name} for dessert. That comes to a total price of £${totalPrice}`;
}
}
menu.addDishToCourse("appetizer","Garlic Mushrooms",3.50);
menu.addDishToCourse("appetizer","Garlic Bread", 2.50);
menu.addDishToCourse("appetizer","Tomato Soup",4.00);
menu.addDishToCourse("appetizer","Breadsticks and Dip",2.00);
menu.addDishToCourse("appetizer","Spicy Chicken Wings",5.00);
menu.addDishToCourse("main","Beef Lasagne",7.25);
menu.addDishToCourse("main","Vegetarian Lasagne",7.25);
menu.addDishToCourse("main","Fish and Chips",6.25);
menu.addDishToCourse("main","Hunters Chicken",7.75);
menu.addDishToCourse("main","Veggie Burger",5.50);
menu.addDishToCourse("dessert","Eton Mess",4.00);
menu.addDishToCourse("dessert","Knickerbocker Glory",3.50);
menu.addDishToCourse("dessert","Chocolate Brownies with Cream",5.00);
menu.addDishToCourse("dessert","Fruit Salad",2.50);
menu.addDishToCourse("dessert","Apple Pie and Custard",4.75);
const meal = menu.generateRandomMeal();
console.log(meal);
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error here in the `appetizers` getter:

```
return this.appetizers;
```

I assume you meant

```
return this._courses.appetizers;
```

to match the setters you have.

Right now you're getter essentially calls itself (because reading `this.appetizers` calls your getter), so you get infinite recursion - hence the stack overflow.

Note: the same problem appears in all your other getters. The setters appear to be correct.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! This definitely helped solved the problem :) I tried the whole thing from scratch and realised I had made a few silly little syntax errors :'D